# How to Populate a dropdown using Enterprise Library 5.0

Tags: asp.net, enterprise-library, daab, data-access-app-block

Is there a simple code to populate a dropdown box using Enterprise Library 5.0 DAAB?

I've tried this, but it is not working:

```
cmbOffice.DataSource = _db.ExecuteDataSet(
      CommandType.Text,
      "select office_id, office_name from office").Tables[0]; 
cmbOffice.DataBind();
```

Comment: Let's try to make your question better. Enterprise library is collection of application blocks with different usage, so what you want to do? Your current question is just suitable for Close - Not a real question.

Comment: I want to populate a dropdown box using Enterprise Library

Comment: cmbOffice.DataSource = _db.ExecuteDataSet(CommandType.Text,"select office_id, office_name from office").Tables[0];
                cmbOffice.DataBind(); i tried this. not working.

Comment: I'm not here for time pass. Trying to solve a problem. Can you try to understand my problem instead of saying "Your current question is just suitable for Close - Not a real question"

Comment: @Vivek the language barrier is causing an issue both ways, I believe. The Enterprise Library contains many parts.  Without knowing which part you are talking about, no person can provide an error.  I gather you wish to use the DAAB.  Updating your question with this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DataSet ds = _db.ExecuteDataSet(
    CommandType.Text,
    "select office_id, office_name from office"); 

cmbOffice.DataSource = ds;
cmbOffice.DataValueField= "office_id";
cmbOffice.DataTextField = "office_name";

cmbOffice.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

cmbOffice.DataSource = _db.ExecuteDataSet(CommandType.Text,"select office_id, office_name from office").Tables[0].defaultView;
cmbOffice.DataBind();